# Where is my TrueTypeFonts located in my computer?

Tags: windows-10, c++, truetype-fonts

I am not sure if this or Stack Overflow is the right place to ask it.

I am having trouble finding where my TrueType font files are. For example `arial.ttf`, I need it for Allegro C++. I am using Windows 10.

What I am trying to do is get my `arial.ttf` file and paste it in my projects so I can use it for my Allegro Tutorial. I have tried to install it from [here](https://github.com/JotJunior/PHP-Boleto-ZF2/blob/master/public/assets/fonts/arial.ttf) but that is the problem! After I install it I don't know where it is!

Comment: Have you looked in `C:\Windows\Fonts`?

Comment: Did you try `c:\Windows\Fonts`? Or `c:\%windir%\Fonts` in general.

Comment: If you right-click on "View Raw" in your link, you can down-load the font to wherever you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Burgi is correct, they are in `C:\Windows\Fonts`. However, navigating there in Explorer will result in a special view rather than a list of files. The easiest way to copy a file out from there is to use the command prompt, since it's not subject to the special folder views. This command copies the normal Arial font file to the current directory:

```
copy C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf .
```

If you're not sure which file corresponds to a certain font, I would look in this Registry key:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts
```

Answer (score 4):

Fonts are stored in the sub-directory `Fonts` of Windows's root directory:

```
%windir%\Fonts
```

Which is usually `c:\Windows\Fonts`.

Comment: `%windir%` expands to `C:\WINDOWS`, so your path there comes out as `c:\C:\WINDOWS\Fonts`, which might not be what you intended.

Comment: Thanks but idk which anwser to accept... should i just leave it like that guys? ( Dawid, @BenN )

Comment: @Dsafds I know the feeling. In such cases, choose the answer that gives the most information or is the most helpful to you and make a mention in the other answer that it is still good but you've chosen the other because: <list reason> it helps us making even better answers.

Comment: @Dsafds Accept the answer which gives you more (or better) information, which is Ben's answer I would say. But you should definitely accept one. If you feel that more answers are useful for you, then just upvote them. But decision is up to you, of course :)

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 look in windows\boot\fonts